# Twitter streaming api OAuth unauthorized

Tags: json, node.js, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I've been fighting with Twitter's streaming api for a while trying to make a simple application in node.js that just reads in tweets real time which I've seen done before. I can send a GET request with

curl https://myusername:mypassword@stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=money

but it returns that I'm unauthorized. Twitter says I need the correct OAuth header (https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests) but I'm not really sure what that even means let alone how to use it. I have my application on dev.twitter.com/apps so I have my tokens and secrets.

Comment: You cannot use that URL anymore as it refers to v1 of the Twitter API which went away in 2012. Per the answer, you need to configure an OAuth setup with your tokens.

Comment: I personally use [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant) for getting access tokens. You can try out the [showcase app](https://grant-oauth.herokuapp.com/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can make requests for data there is a back and forth to 'login' to twitter and get the rights to make a real request. This is what OAuth does. Since you are using node, use one of the several Twitter libraries out there to do it for you. I use the 'twitter' module like this:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var client = new Twitter(cfg); //cfg contains the tokens and secrets
client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: query}, function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
            console.log(tweet);
        });
});
```

The module docs describe the four auth values you will need in the `cfg` object.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter